# Is it possible to use loaded h2o grids for stacked ensembles?

Tags: r, h2o, grid-search

I am currently working on multiple datasets using differend machine learning methods with R and the `h2o` library. Since I have several 10-fold cross validations for each dataset, I ran a random GridSearch for each and saved the grids using `h2o.saveGrid`. When I loaded those grids again to build ensembles using  `h2o.stackedEnsemble` it returns the error message

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Failed to find the xval predictions frame id. Looks like keep_cross_validation_predictions wasn't set when building the models.
```

However, `keep_cross_validation_predictions` is set to true and it runs perfectly fine if I use the grid without saving and loading it. So I guess that something along the line of loading and saving gets lost.

Does anyone have an idea if there is a way to use loaded grids for stacked ensembles in `h2o` or is it simply not supported yet? I appreciate any insight since this would save me a lot of time. I cannot keep them all in my h2o cluster all the time

I am using R 3.6.3 and h2o 3.32.0.1

A minimal working example does reproduces the error for me:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

train_data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100,1,2),
                         x1 = rnorm(100,5,5),
                         x2 = rnorm(100,4,4),
                         x3 = rnorm(100,3,3),
                         x4 = rnorm(100,2,2))

params <- list(max_depth = seq(1, 6, 1),
               sample_rate = seq(0.2, 1.0, 0.1))
search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_models = 10, seed = 2102)

train_h2o <- as.h2o(train_data,destination_frame = "Train")

gbm_grid <- h2o.grid("gbm",y = "y", x = c("x1","x2","x3","x4"), training_frame = train_h2o,
                     grid_id = "gbm_1",  nfolds = 10, ntrees = 50, seed= 1111,
                     keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                     hyper_params = params, 
                     search_criteria = search_criteria)
h2o.performance(test_ens)

test_ens <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(y = "y", x = c("x1","x2","x3","x4"), training_frame = train_h2o,
                                metalearner_algorithm = "glm", model_id = "Ens1",
                                base_models = gbm_grid@model_ids[1:10])

h2o.saveGrid(grid_directory = paste0(getwd(),"/Data"),grid_id = "gbm_1")
```

When loading the grid, training the ensemble produces the error

```
h2o.removeAll()

train_h2o <- as.h2o(train_data,destination_frame = "Train")
gbm_grid <- h2o.loadGrid(paste0(getwd(),"/Data/gbm_1"))

test_ens <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(y = "y", x = c("x1","x2","x3","x4"), training_frame = train_h2o,
                                metalearner_algorithm = "glm", model_id = "Ens2",
                                base_models = gbm_grid@model_ids[1:10])
```

I have also tried setting `export_checkpoints_dir` in `h2o.grid` and manually loading all the models (including their auto-generated cv folds which are, contrary to `h2o.saveGrid`, also saved this way) but it does not change anything.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacked Ensemble requires the CV predictions from the base learners, which are not currently being saved when you save the models to disk via `h2o.saveModel()`.  They need to be saved and then reloaded into the model when using `h2o.loadModel()`, so that they're available for the metalearning step of the Stacked Ensemble algorithm.

**Update:**  This [feature](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5923) has been added, and is available in H2O 3.32.0.3.  Link to download latest stable version of H2O is [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html).